# Implementing Lexicographic Ordering to Find Unique Permutations

Tags: c++, permutation

I am attempting to implement an algorithm to generate unique permutations in lexicographic order described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations#Generation_in_lexicographic_order). The following is my implementation.

```
void My_Permute(string word) {
    sort(word.begin(),word.end());
    int size = word.size(); 
    while (true) {
        cout << word << endl;
        int i = size - 2;  
        for (; i >= 0; --i) { 
            if (word[i] < word[i+1]) break; 
        } 
        if (i <= -1) break; 
        swap(word[i],word[i+1]);
        cout << word << endl;
        reverse(word.begin()+i+1,word.end());
    } 
}
```

I am sure the algorithm is correct, so what is wrong with my implementation? My function is misses some permutations. The following shows my output compared with std::next_permutation on the input `abcd`.

```
My_Permute             std::next_permutation
abcd                   abcd
abdc                   abdc
abdc                   acbd
adbc                   adbc
adcb                   adcb
dacb                   bacd
dbca                   bcad
dcba                   bcda
dcab                   bdac
dcba                   bdca
dcba                   cabd
                       cadb
                       cbad
                       ...
```

Comment: Stylistic improvement suggestion: instead of `if (i <= -1)`, write `if (i < 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing step #2 from the linked algorithm

```
void Permute(string word) {
    sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    int size = word.size();
    while (true) {
        cout << word << endl;
        // Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1].
        // If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
        int i = size - 2;
        for (; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (word[i] < word[i+1])
                break;
        }
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        // Find the largest index l such that a[k] < a[l].
        // Since k + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies k < l.
        int j = size - 1;
        for (; ; --j) {
            if (word[i] < word[j])
                break;
        }
        // Swap a[k] with a[l].
        swap(word[i], word[j]);
        // Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the
        // final element a[n].
        reverse(word.begin() + i + 1, word.end());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
adbc
adcb
bacd
badc
bcad
bcda
bdac
bdca
cabd
cadb
cbad
cbda
cdab
cdba
dabc
dacb
dbac
dbca
dcab
dcba
```

24 (i.e. 4!) rows, as expected

By the way, you should [avoid "using namespace std"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) as much as possible.

Comment: Ironically, you use `using namespace std` it in your solution ;)

Comment: @idealistikz only to avoid the complication of reformatting your code so the difference in the versions would be clearer: but I tested it [here](http://ideone.com/7eZREW) without it

Comment: I like the website you used. Thanks for the knowledge.